# Typescript: how to disable spec.ts file generation?

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, angular, transpiler

i'm developing an Angular2 app with Typescript and every time i run the Typescript transpiler it creates `spec.ts` files.
They are unit tests for the source files because the convention for Angular2 applications is to have this file for each `.ts` file.

Since at the moment i don't want to do any test, i would like to temporaly disable the generation of spec.ts files, that are a bit messy to handle with my source files.

Do you know how to do that?

**EDIT:** here is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "typings/main.d.ts",
    "typings/main",
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: could you show us what your tsconfig.json file looks like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure your tsconfig.json file to achieve this. 
You can specify which files to compile by adding them to the files array or you can tell typescript to exclude a certain file or folder by including it in the exclude array.

Here is the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) from the official docs.

But as far as i can tell you can't provide a patter like so: '/**.spec.ts'